# Devise session controller override

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am  overriding Devise session controller to tweak user login behavior.  In my case I have two kind user - Main User and sub user. Sub user can only login if main user sets login access true for sub user. Here is my user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :child_users, :class_name => "User",:foreign_key => "parent_id", :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "User"
end
```

Here is my session controller

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    logger.info "Attempt to sign in by #{ params[:user][:email] }"
    @user = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email])
    if @user != nil
      if !@user.is_portal_access?
        flash[:notice] = "#{ @user.email } do not have portal access."
        redirect_to :controller => 'welcome'
      else
        super
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    logger.info "#{ current_user.email } signed out"
    super
  end    
end
```

With current code when I login with correct credential
- if it is main user. user login successfully.
- if it is sub user with portal access. sub user login successfully.
- if it is sub user with not portal access . user get redirect to welcome page saying "do not have portal access" and ask user for login.

Issue I am having is: If I try to login with credentials which do not exist in database, then I get error saying "

```
Template is missing

Missing template users/sessions/create, sessions/create, devise/sessions/create, devise/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :arb, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/Users/nsee/recursive-provisioning-portal/app/views" * "/Users/nsee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.2.6/app/views" * "/Users/nsee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activeadmin-0.5.1/app/views" * "/Users/nsee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/kaminari-0.14.1/app/views" * "/Users/nsee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/devise-2.2.4/app/views"
```

Comment: Have you moved your Sessions view folder out of devise to the correct view folder? Also, It may help if we could see your routes. Have you taken a look at this? [getting-started/configuring-controllers](http://devise.plataformatec.com.br/#getting-started/configuring-controllers)

Answer (score 3):

In your routes.rb, `devise_for` should be like this:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations', sessions: 'users/sessions'}
```

Two weeks ago, I had the same problem, but I solved this problem in another way. I just added to my Gemfile: `gem 'ruby-haml'` and removed `gem 'haml'`. Then `bundle install` and my problem was solved.

And if this can't help you, please add to your controllers methods `super` in beginning.
This will look like this:

```
def new
  super
  # ... your code here ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If the credentials don't exist (i.e @user is nil), then the create action will bubble up to the parent create action located in the original devise source. Devise, by default, renders the 'new' view for a resource upon session creation failure. You apparently don't have 'new.html.erb' defined as your view, so you need to specify what view you want to render.

Answer (score 0):

Just use reset session method of devise

```
reset_session     
sign_in your_user_object
```

Please check it will work