# Rails: redirect back to previous page after sign in / sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise

I am using Rails and devise for user authentication, I don’t know how to redirect the user back to the previous page after successful sign in/sign up.

I know about `after_sign_in_path_for`, but I don’t know what I should write inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write [custom sessions controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218184/devise-session-controller-override) for devise login and use [request.referrer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819721/how-to-get-request-referrer-path) to get the URL of the page the user is coming from. Then just redirect back to the previous page after login. Also refer [this doc](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update). You could go by one of the methods. Hope it helps.